# Deploying a SpaCY application in Flask using Docker

Tags: python, visual-studio, docker, flask, spacy

I have a SpaCY application written in Python Flask to detect Named Entities which is to be used as a service in tandem with another application. It was created as a Python app using Visual Studio and the virtual environment is Python Version (3.6). I deployed it on Azure as a windows VM and works great as is.

Next step was to deploy using Docker. I created a Dockerfile, built an image and ran it. It does run and shows the url and port. But upon accessing any defined route I get a "This site cannot be reached".

I am able to directly run the python project or through visual studio and have no problems which led me to believe that the problem is in my Dockerfile or my understanding of it.

As a guide I started following Microsoft's Azure tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-prepare-app) and used the sample project : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/aci-helloworld and I was able to build a dockerfile and access its routes.

Now it leads me to believe that either SpaCY, my dockerfile or some incompatibility between SpaCY and Docker is causing this. Any help on this would be greatly appreciate. If I am missing any information, I would be happy to add it.

My project structure :

- SpaCYParser

  - env
  - runserver.py ( This will fire up the server )
  - SpaCYParser

    - **init**.py
    - parser.py

runserver.py

```
from SpaCYParser import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

parser.py

```
from flask import request, jsonify, make_response
from SpaCYParser import app
import json, spacy
from SpaCYParser import parserOutput
from SpaCYParser import Entity
from SpaCYParser import NEREntities

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/test')
def ping():
    print("hello world")
    return "HELLO WORLD"
@app.route('/parse')
def parse():
    # NER Specific code.
```

My Docker File :

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6

LABEL Name=mparser Version=0.0.1
ENV LISTEN_PORT=5000
EXPOSE 5000

WORKDIR /mparser
COPY . /mparser
# Using pip:
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "runserver.py"]
```

Docker log :

```
PS C:\Users\STanwar\Documents\GitHub\mParser\SpaCYParser\SpaCYParser> docker build --rm -f ../Dockerfile -t mparser:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.382GB
Step 1/8 : FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6
 ---> 839b35a9f270
Step 2/8 : LABEL Name=mparser Version=0.0.1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1abd09524d8d
Step 3/8 : ENV LISTEN_PORT=5000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 896d10f35e29
Step 4/8 : EXPOSE 5000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> aa6010d2ceea
Step 5/8 : WORKDIR /mparser
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9f5860f4b559
Step 6/8 : COPY . /mparser
 ---> 800bc0c19ce7
Step 7/8 : RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 3deceaf0c24e
Requirement already satisfied: click==6.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (6.7)
Collecting cymem==1.31.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/9e/273fbea507de99166c11cd0cb3fde1ac01b5bc724d9a407a2f927ede91a1/cymem-1.31.2.tar.gz
Collecting cytoolz==0.8.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/e6/ccc124714dcc1bd511e64ddafb4d5d20ada2533b92e3173a4cf09e0d0831/cytoolz-0.8.2.tar.gz (386kB)
Collecting dill==0.2.8.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/78/8b96476f4ae426db71c6e86a8e6a81407f015b34547e442291cd397b18f3/dill-0.2.8.2.tar.gz (150kB)
Collecting Flask<1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/48/f1936dadac2326b3d73f2fe0a964a87d16be16eb9d7fc56f09c1bea3d17c/Flask-0.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (81kB)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous==0.24 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2==2.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe==1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (1.0)
Collecting msgpack-numpy==0.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/43/393e30e2768b0357541ac95891f96b80ccc4d517e0dd2fa3042fc8926538/msgpack_numpy-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting msgpack-python==0.5.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/20/6eca772d1a5830336f84aca1d8198e5a3f4715cd1c7fc36d3cc7f7185091/msgpack-python-0.5.6.tar.gz (138kB)
Collecting murmurhash==0.28.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/31/c8c1ecafa44db30579c8c457ac7a0f819e8b1dbc3e58308394fff5ff9ba7/murmurhash-0.28.0.tar.gz
Collecting numpy==1.14.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/1e/116ad560de97694e2d0c1843a7a0075cc9f49e922454d32f49a80eb6f1f2/numpy-1.14.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (12.2MB)
Collecting pathlib==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/aa/9b065a76b9af472437a0059f77e8f962fe350438b927cb80184c32f075eb/pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz (49kB)
Collecting pip==9.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/95/a05b56bb975efa78d3557efa36acaf9cf5d2fd0ee0062060493687432e03/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
Collecting plac==0.9.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/9b/62c60d2f5bc135d2aa1d8c8a86aaf84edb719a59c7f11a4316259e61a298/plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting preshed==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/ac/7c17b1fd54b60972785b646d37da2826311cca70842c011c4ff84fbe95e0/preshed-1.0.0.tar.gz (89kB)
Collecting pyreadline==2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/7c/d724ef1ec3ab2125f38a1d53285745445ec4a8f19b9bb0761b4064316679/pyreadline-2.1.zip (109kB)
Collecting regex==2017.4.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/62/c0c0d762ffd4ffaf39f372eb8561b8d491a11ace5a7884610424a8b40f95/regex-2017.04.05.tar.gz (601kB)
Collecting setuptools==39.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/d7/04a0b689d3035143e2ff288f4b9ee4bf6ed80585cc121c90bfd85a1a8c2e/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (569kB)
Collecting six==1.11.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting spacy==2.0.11 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/31/e60f88751e48851b002f78a35221d12300783d5a43d4ef12fbf10cca96c3/spacy-2.0.11.tar.gz (17.6MB)
Collecting termcolor==1.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/48/a76be51647d0eb9f10e2a4511bf3ffb8cc1e6b14e9e4fab46173aa79f981/termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting thinc==6.10.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 23))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/fd/e9f36081e6f53699943381858848f3b4d759e0dd03c43b98807dde34c252/thinc-6.10.2.tar.gz (1.2MB)
Collecting toolz==0.9.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/d0/a73c15bbeda3d2e7b381a36afb0d9cd770a9f4adc5d1532691013ba881db/toolz-0.9.0.tar.gz (45kB)
Collecting tqdm==4.23.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 25))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/24/6ab1df969db228aed36a648a8959d1027099ce45fad67532b9673d533318/tqdm-4.23.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42kB)
Collecting ujson==1.35 (from -r requirements.txt (line 26))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/c4/79f3409bc710559015464e5f49b9879430d8f87498ecdc335899732e5377/ujson-1.35.tar.gz (192kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug==0.14.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 27)) (0.14.1)
Collecting wrapt==1.10.11 (from -r requirements.txt (line 28))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/47/66897906448185fcb77fc3c2b1bc20ed0ecca81a0f2f88eda3fc5a34fc3d/wrapt-1.10.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: cymem, cytoolz, dill, msgpack-python, murmurhash, pathlib, preshed, pyreadline, regex, spacy, termcolor, thinc, toolz, ujson, wrapt
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cymem: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cymem: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/55/8d/4a/f6328252aa2aaec0b1cb906fd96a1566d77f0f67701071ad13
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cytoolz: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cytoolz: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/f8/b1/86/c92e4d36b690208fff8471711b85eaa6bc6d19860a86199a09
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dill: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dill: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e2/5d/17/f87cb7751896ac629b435a8696f83ee75b11029f5d6f6bda72
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for msgpack-python: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for msgpack-python: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/d5/de/86/7fa56fda12511be47ea0808f3502bc879df4e63ab168ec0406
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for murmurhash: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for murmurhash: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b8/94/a4/f69f8664cdc1098603df44771b7fec5fd1b3d8364cdd83f512
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pathlib: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pathlib: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/f9/b2/4a/68efdfe5093638a9918bd1bb734af625526e849487200aa171
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for preshed: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for preshed: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8f/85/06/2d132fb649a6bbcab22487e4147880a55b0dd0f4b18fdfd6b5
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyreadline: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyreadline: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/70/66/59/590265c96902c7616243300c8f0d8ffe7800253ad55dfa9aa1
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for regex: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for regex: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/75/07/38/3c16b529d50cb4e0cd3dbc7b75cece8a09c132692c74450b01
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for spacy: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for spacy: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for spacy: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for spacy: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for spacy: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for spacy: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/fb/00/28/75c85d5135e7d9a100639137d1847d41e914ed16c962d467e4
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for termcolor: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for termcolor: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/7c/06/54/bc84598ba1daf8f970247f550b175aaaee85f68b4b0c5ab2c6
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for thinc: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for thinc: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for thinc: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/d8/5c/3e/9acf5d9974fb1c9e7b467563ea5429c9325f67306e93147961
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for toolz: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for toolz: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/f4/0c/f6/ce6b2d1aa459ee97cc3c0f82236302bd62d89c86c700219463
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for ujson: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for ujson: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/28/77/e4/0311145b9c2e2f01470e744855131f9e34d6919687550f87d1
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for wrapt: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for wrapt: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/48/5d/04/22361a593e70d23b1f7746d932802efe1f0e523376a74f321e
Successfully built cymem cytoolz dill msgpack-python murmurhash pathlib preshed pyreadline regex spacy termcolor thinc toolz ujson wrapt
Installing collected packages: cymem, toolz, cytoolz, dill, Flask, numpy, msgpack-python, msgpack-numpy, murmurhash, pathlib, pip, plac, preshed, pyreadline, regex, setuptools, six, wrapt, tqdm, termcolor, thinc, ujson, spacy
  Found existing installation: Flask 1.0.2
    Uninstalling Flask-1.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled Flask-1.0.2
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
  Found existing installation: setuptools 39.2.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-39.2.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-39.2.0
Successfully installed Flask-0.12.4 cymem-1.31.2 cytoolz-0.8.2 dill-0.2.8.2 msgpack-numpy-0.4.1 msgpack-python-0.5.6 murmurhash-0.28.0 numpy-1.14.5 pathlib-1.0.1 pip-9.0.3 plac-0.9.6 preshed-1.0.0 pyreadline-2.1 regex-2017.4.5 setuptools-39.0.1 six-1.11.0 spacy-2.0.11 termcolor-1.1.0 thinc-6.10.2 toolz-0.9.0 tqdm-4.23.4 ujson-1.35 wrapt-1.10.11
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Removing intermediate container 3deceaf0c24e
 ---> cdaa3e79b5d1
Step 8/8 : CMD ["python", "runserver.py"]
 ---> Running in 38bd3ddd0b2f
Removing intermediate container 38bd3ddd0b2f
 ---> 142755fee0a2
Successfully built 142755fee0a2
Successfully tagged mparser:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
PS C:\Users\STanwar\Documents\GitHub\mParser\SpaCYParser\SpaCYParser> docker run mparser:latest
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

My thanks in advance. 
Sharad

Additional Background: 
I have experience with Python with some school projects. This is my first instance using and deploying with Docker. Need for Docker arose when we decided to deploy our project for different domains( US and Canada due to the sensitivity of data) and building a docker image which can be used to spawn instances(containers?) easily.

Comment: Could you show the `docker run` command you're using to spin up a container?

Comment: @dablackreaper did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I am looking for an answer to this question as well. Did you manage?